# PostgreSQL difference between "character varying" and "character varying[]" via pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, types, varchar

What is the difference between the following two data types?

I thought that `character varying[]` is used when we want to use also Length constraint. However, from what I see within pgAdmin, we can use this constraint also with `character varying`.

[image: columns]

Comment: text vs array of text. Or in descriptive manner, single username and multiple emails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text vs array of text. It represents single user name with possible multiple emails stored as array of type `VARCHAR(100)`.

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
   username character varying(100),
   email character varying(100)[]
);

INSERT INTO tab(username, email) VALUES ('user', '{"a@domain.com", "b@domain.com"}');

SELECT *, email[1], email[2]
FROM tab;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eb43d3e2bc54d2ed125a74e54ef145f4)**

Output:

```
+-----------+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| username  |            email             |    email      |    email     |
+-----------+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| user      | {a@domain.com,b@domain.com}  | a@domain.com  | b@domain.com |
+-----------+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

"character varying" (or varchar, for short) is a string (text) field with varying length (up to 100 characters in your case). The `[]` denotes an array. I.e., "character varying[]" is an **array** of such "character varying" strings.